# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Tag' and 'Tag'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, type-conversion

I'm trying to scrap HTML data from a website and then add my own CSS style to the code. I'm using Beautiful soup to scrap the data and convert my own  tag to HTML.

This is the code

```
        word = t.clipboard_get()

        # Web Scrapping
        url="https://www.vajehyab.com/?q="

        response = requests.get(f"{url}{word}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        meaning = soup.find(["div", "style"], attrs={"id": "wordbox"},)


        # Style
        style = """<style>
            #wordbox{
                width: 500px;
            }
        </style>"""

        css_to_tag = BeautifulSoup(style, 'html.parser')
        css = css_to_tag.find("style")

        meaning += css
```

But in the last line, when I try to combine them I get this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Tag' and 'Tag'

Is there any way to add HTML tags inside another in beautiful soup

Comment: Please provide what {word} is.

Answer (score 0):

(I **strongly** recommend [reading the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) a bit.)
I think what you're looking for is `.append`

```py
meaning.append(css)
```

should do what you're wanting to.

Comment: Ah yes, that appended the CSS to HTML, but the CSS didn't work which I think is because of the way Beautifulsoup works.

Anyway thanks a lot for your answer, it definitely helped.

Comment: @ArshiyaZandi What do you mean by "CSS didn't work"? How are you processing the result of your code? Are you writing it to a new HTML file and attempting to open that in a browser?

Comment: No, I actually thought CSS can work in tkinter's label widget, but it seems it doesn't. so I actually have to style the widget itself which is proving to be a hard thing to do with the content I have. If you have any tips let me know, anything will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.